# Cumulative vs. Tiered Calculation in SQL Query or Inline Table Value Function with Conditional Logic?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working with two tables of data, but different methodologies to derive two distinct desired outputs below.

The first is a cumulative tier calculation and the second is a just a tiered lookup based on a range. I need to be able to return this calculation for a row item transaction based on some JOINS using foreign keys to other dimension tables, namely Accounts and Regions and Tier Type. For example, a single account could have a calculation be either cumulative or tiered based on the region's and/or account's ID.

Link to [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e29c0927c9ec1b7c0deb2567df600116)

| Type ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Cumulative |
| 2 | Tiered |

Tiered table:

| Account ID | Type ID | Region ID | TierNo | Min | Max | Total A | Total B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 10000 | .90 | .10 |
| 101 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 10001 | 30000 | .60 | .40 |
| 101 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 30001 | 100000 | .40 | .60 |
| 101 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 100001 | 500000 | .40 | .60 |
| 101 | 1 | 2 | 5 | 500001 | 999999999999 | .20 | .80 |
| 102 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 7800 | .80 | .20 |
| 102 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 7801 | 12800 | .70 | .30 |
| 102 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 12801 | 34000 | .60 | .40 |
| 102 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 34001 | 50000 | .50 | .50 |
| 102 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 5000 1 | 999999999999 | .50 | .50 |
| 103 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 10000 | .90 | .10 |
| 103 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 10001 | 30000 | .60 | .40 |
| 103 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 30001 | 100000 | .40 | .60 |
| 103 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 100001 | 500000 | .40 | .60 |
| 103 | 2 | 1 | 5 | 500001 | 999999999999 | .20 | .80 |

Current table sample:

| Trans ID | Account ID | Type ID | Region ID | GrossAmt | Total A % | Total A $ | Net Amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100001 | 101 | 1 | 2 | 42650 |  |  |  |
| 100002 | 102 | 1 | 3 | 42650 |  |  |  |
| 100003 | 103 | 2 | 1 | 42650 |  |  |  |

Desired output:

| Trans ID | Account ID | Type ID | Region ID | GrossAmt | Total A % | Total A $ | Net Amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100001 | 101 | 1 | 2 | 42650 | 0.611 | 26059.99 | 16589.99 |
| 100002 | 102 | 1 | 3 | 42650 | 0.628 | 26784.98 | 15864.99 |
| 100003 | 103 | 2 | 1 | 42650 | 0.40 | 17060.00 | 25590.00 |

I've been able to make some edits to a previous post to get the accounts, but can't seem to figure out the logic for the tiered lookup value in TransID 100003.

Ideally, I'd prefer to create this logic in a table value function (or two) and then incorporate it into a View that I'll use for reporting in a web form using C#.

```
SELECT
  c.*,
  [Total A %] = t.Total / c.GrossAmt,
  [Total A $] = t.Total,
  [Net Amt]   = c.GrossAmt - t.Total
FROM #temp c
INNER JOIN Accounts a ON a.[Account ID] = c.[Account ID]
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      Total = SUM((v.ActualMax - t.[Min]) * t.[Total A %])
    FROM [dbo].[Tiered Table] t
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES(
      CASE WHEN c.GrossAmt < t.[Max] THEN c.GrossAmt ELSE t.[Max] END
    )) v(ActualMax)
    WHERE c.GrossAmt > t.[Min] AND t.[Account ID] = c.[Account ID]
) t;
```

Any ideas or guidance would be extremely helpful and appreciated.

Comment: If you were to provide sample data as DDL+DML e.g. a DBFiddle I'd have a look. But I'm not typing it all in myself :)

Comment: Thanks, Dale. Attached a link to DB FIddle.

Comment: FYI, while quoting columns names is allowed, its not best practice with SQL Server, if you need to escape a column name (which you should avoid if possible) then us square brackets `[]`.

Comment: So you mention the issue lies with TransId "10003" which doesn't exist? I assume you mean "100003". However the row which is different between your desired results and your actual results is TransId "100002"? Can you clarify please. And can you explain what the difference is between a tiered and cumulative balance?

Comment: Right, I know - I just ran through it in the example for DB Fiddle - my actual table create statements and field headers are more formal and are consistent, spaced out names using brackets, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: apologies, i missed an extra zero in the TransID reference, it's fixed now. 
the cumulative balance is derived from aggregating the difference for each tier - cumulatively based on the percentage in each tier. So, for acct 101 in region 2, you'd have 90% of the gross amt for anything up to $10k, and then 60% of the next tranche of 19,999.99, and so on until the grossamt is totaled out. the "Tiered" would just be the equivalent of a Vlookup value, so if the fee is $42,650, then it would fall into the third tier between 30k and 100k, so it'd just be a flat 40% of the gross amt.

Comment: I say again though, the tiered results are for transid **10002** not **10003**?

Comment: Apologies, I mixed up the tiered results for those transactions. The tables should be corrected now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It seems to be a simple matter of `AND` `OR` logic.** You need to exclude rows which are `TypeID = 2` and also have their maximum *below* the level of `GrossAmt`.

Then you just conditionally aggregate either the total amount (for tiered rows only, there will be only one row) or just the amount for that tier (for cumulative tiers).

```sql
SELECT
  c.*,
  [Total A %] = t.Total / c.GrossAmt,
  [Total A $] = t.Total,
  [Net Amt]   = c.GrossAmt - t.Total
FROM CurrentData c
INNER JOIN Accounts a ON a.[AccountID] = c.[AccountID]
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      Total = SUM(CASE WHEN t.TypeID = 2 THEN v.GrossAmt ELSE (v.ActualMax - t.[Min]) END * t.[Total A])
    FROM [dbo].[Tiers] t
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES(
      CASE WHEN c.GrossAmt < t.[Max] THEN c.GrossAmt ELSE t.[Max] END,
      c.GrossAmt
    )) v(ActualMax, GrossAmt)
    WHERE t.[AccountID] = c.[AccountID]
      AND t.TypeID = c.TypeID
      AND t.RegionID = c.RegionID
      AND c.GrossAmt > t.[Min]
      AND (t.TypeID = 1 OR c.GrossAmt <= t.Max)
) t;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=00e3fe8906bc04002fe4600182341064)

> The second `CROSS APPLY` is only necessary because of aggregating outer values. You don't need this if you place it in a function, as shown in your previous question.

Note that you should use half-open intervals here. In other words, either `Min` or `Max` should be exclusive. Otherwise there may be values that can "fall through the cracks".

Comment: Eh? Looks right to me. As mentioned, there are issues with edge cases due to the tier values not quite meeting up. Could fix it with `LAG` or by just manually editing the values

Comment: Ops, sorry, OP must have changed the sample data. I just ran your query against the data I copied out earlier.

Comment: OP changed the data in the post without changing the fiddle

Comment: Thank you, both! And apologies for the errors/anomalies in my initial  posts. As a follow up, what's the best way to systemize this calculation to render the denormalized results after a "Save" or "Update" button has been clicked in a Web Form? i.e., ASP.NET...

Comment: "systemize this calculation" not sure what this means? Are you asking whether to create a view, stored procedure or inline table valued function? Over using a raw query?

Comment: Yes, for example, I'd like to provide a web form for people to enter in a small amount of requisite data and then upon saving it within the form, the calculations would automatically populate previously empty fields in the form. I'm just not sure what would be the best approach, a view, SP or inline table valued function to do that.

Comment: A view or a TVF is good, but you will still need more code around it to actually select the right columns and pass in the data. You could do any of those options, they are all good, although I would probably avoid a view given the complexity of the query: filters may not perform well if done from outside the view, whereas a TVF or procedure can get the filters all the way into the subqueries

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. So, if I create a web form that people fill out and then (ostensibly) it would write the raw data inputs into a denormalized staging table. Then, I would think, the data would be brought into the main fact table via a stored procedure (maybe?), but then I'm not really sure how to render the resulting fee calculations to users in the web form.

Comment: The challenge is the calculated results I need to be able to display are all recursive and render differently based on selected filters the user selects for each fee-generating transaction.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you there, I don't have your project in front of me, and I don't know your setup (sounds like you have some kind of DW setup or something, unclear), and you probably know better what you need. Perhaps you need to pass in a `TypeID` to filter on? I don't know, and I'm not sure if anyone is going to be able to help you for that kind of thing on [so].